# How to show dynamic data in internationalization react i18n

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

Hey guys I have a question regarding react i18n. I have a scenario where I'm translating like this

```
const context = history?.actionData?.status ||
  history?.context ||
  history.action ||
  "N/A";

t("action-history-description", {...history, context)
```

and the `action-history-description` string looks like this

```
"{{context}} - ({{actionData.user.name}} - {{actionData.user.phone"
```

What I want to do is move the context condition inside the string. so the string should look like this

```
"{{actionData.status || context || action || 'N/A'}} - ({{actionData.user.name}} - {{actionData.user.phone"
```

and then i18n does the rest of the job. So if I have the `actionData.status` its value is shown. If not then context and so on.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.
btw: the context feature of i18next works differently: https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/context